# Run a script only at shutdown (not log off or restart) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, script, shutdown, shell-script

Is there any way to run a script only at shutdown?

I mean, only when the computer is really shutting down to off state. This script should not run when doing just a log off or restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shutdown on OS X is completed by running a file '/sbin/shutdown_proxy.sh.'

If this file was to be renamed to .old and replaced with a custom coded file it will complete any command you can use on shutdown.

It's a little difficult to find information however this may help:

http://bogner.sh/2012/11/os-x-run-commands-before-shutdown/